# Some strings are not translating in dokan pro using loco translate

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, dokan

[image: My translation not working]

[image: Here is the output]

As you can see, i struggle only with few words and can't find a way through. I need help, if you know how to make this translate work. Thank you